# Centering Logo Items Directly Above the Adjoining Descriptions

Tags: enumerate, tcolorbox, enumitem, logos

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbox{\logo}{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
    colframe=green,
    colback=green!35,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    tcbox raise base}

\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{enumerate}[label=\logo{\arabic*}]
\item I would like to center the logo above the sentence.
\\[10pt]
\item I would like to center the logo above the sentence.
\\[10pt]
\item I would like to center the logo above the sentence.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: enter code here]

QUESTION: How may I modify the code so that the numbered logos appear centered and above respectively, the adjoining sentences?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a new environment `cenumerate` that centers its contents:

```
\newcounter{cenum}
\newcommand\cenumsep{}  
\newenvironment{cenumerate}{%
  \setcounter{cenum}{0}%
  \def\cenumsep{\def\cenumsep{\bigskip}}% \bigskip is the distance between items, change as needed
  \begin{center}%
}{%
  \end{center}%
}
```

and a command `\citem` that numbers the items:

```
\newcommand\citem{%
  \refstepcounter{cenum}%
  \par\cenumsep\logo{\arabic{cenum}}%
  \par\nobreak\medskip\noindent\ignorespaces% \medskip is the distance between label and text, change as needed
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\logo}{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
    colframe=green,
    colback=green!35,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    tcbox raise base}

\newcounter{cenum}
\newcommand\cenumsep{}  
\newenvironment{cenumerate}{%
  \setcounter{cenum}{0}%
  \def\cenumsep{\def\cenumsep{\bigskip}}% \bigskip is the distance between items, change as needed
  \begin{center}%
}{%
  \end{center}%
}
\newcommand\citem{%
  \refstepcounter{cenum}%
  \par\cenumsep\logo{\arabic{cenum}}%
  \par\nobreak\medskip\noindent\ignorespaces% \medskip is the distance between label and text, change as needed
}

\begin{document}
Some text before. Some text before. Some text before.
Some text before. Some text before. Some text before.
\begin{cenumerate}
\citem I would like to center the logo above the sentence.
\citem I would like to center the logo above the sentence.
\citem I would like to center the logo above the sentence.
\end{cenumerate}
Some text after. Some text after. Some text after.
Some text after. Some text after. Some text after.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer.

Comment: Pages can be broken between the green box and the text.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I've modified the code.

Comment: @mlchristians I've modified my answer to avoid page breaks after the label.