# Producing Non-Enumerated Items in a Customized Enumeration

Tags: pdftex, lists, enumerate, page-breaking, tcolorbox

This question extends the one posed in [Centering Logo Items Directly Above the Adjoining Descriptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615864/centering-logo-items-directly-above-the-adjoining-descriptions)

Consider the expanded MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\newcommand*{\boldcheckmark}{%
  \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    LineWidth=.5pt, 
  }{\checkmark}%
}



\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\logo}{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
    colframe=red,
    colback=red!35,
    top=0pt,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    tcbox raise base}

\newcounter{cenum}
\newcommand\cenumsep{}  
\newenvironment{cenumerate}{%
  \setcounter{cenum}{0}%
  \def\cenumsep{\def\cenumsep{\bigskip}}% \bigskip is the distance between items, change as needed
  \begin{center}%
}{%
  \end{center}%
}
\newcommand\citem{%
  \refstepcounter{cenum}%
  \par\cenumsep\logo{\arabic{cenum}}%
  \par\nobreak\medskip\noindent\ignorespaces% \medskip is the distance between label and text, change as needed
}

\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{cenumerate}
\citem The item logo is centered above the sentence. $\checkmark$
\citem[] \textbf{\textcolor{red}{This sentence is part of the above item, and so I do not want it enumerated.}}

\citem The item logo is centered above the sentence. $\checkmark$

\citem The item logo is centered above the sentence. $\checkmark$
\end{cenumerate}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

The second `\citem` is intended to be part of the first; and so, is not to be enumerated.

In a regular `\enumerate`, inserting `\item[]` in place of `\item` accomplishes this quite nicely, and even allows for a pagebreak at `\item[]` if need be---which is also what I would like to have happen here (assuming that `\citem[]` worked analogously to `\item[]`).

QUESTION: Can anyone advise me how I may modify the above code so that I may, (1) produce an item in a list with no item number, that (2) will allow for a page break at that non-enumerated item if need be (like `\item[]` does for a standard enumeration list)?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd use a standard latex list, but in either case, why don't you just have a paragraph break (blank line) before continuation paragraphs that are part of the preceding item, why prefix them with `\citem` ? in a normal enumerate (which this could be, just styled differently) you should use a blank line not `\item[]` for such a paragraph

Comment: @David Carlisle I need this for a multicolumn environment. And so, I have used `item[]` when the description is very long to encourage a page break. I have found that if I use something like \\ within the item, I do not get the page break where I want and then the whole item is placed on the following page, leaving a big (ugly)  gap on the previous page. With `item[]`, whose gap-width I can adjust on an ad hoc basis, I get the page break where I want and the  previous 2-column page is nicely filled.

Comment: multicolumn isn't an issue for lists and item[] doesn't encourage a page break, it just prevents a page break between the label and the item text. the page break is just a normal page/column  break.  `\\ ` doesn't end a paragraph blank lines denote pargraph end.  `\item[]` is just logically the wrong markup if the following text is part of preceding item. This will be even more important if accessibility tagging is used as the structure does not match the meaning.

Comment: @David Carlisle Perhaps "encourage" was a poor choice of words on my part. I have used  `\item[]` many times and Latex will break the page at `\item[]` when it wants to because it considers it the beginning of a new item. I, on the other hand, the the page break I need and the presentation still show that the two separate blocks of text are still part of the same item. If I skip a space, as I (if I interpret you correctly), Latex will consider it all part of the same item and will break the page too soon.  *(cont'd)*

Comment: @David Carlisle (I am using a set of commands that you suggested in a previous post that fills the page from top to bottom with variable spacing; didn't note that in the last comment.)

Comment: as I say the page break penalty at `\item[]` isn't diferent to the page break penalty at a paragraph break.

Comment: well that's OK just make the parskip I just used in the answer stretchy enough (it's set to bigskipamount here which is a bit sretchy already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red text is logically part of the first, multi-paragraph, item so can be marked up as such.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\newcommand*{\boldcheckmark}{%
  \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    LineWidth=.5pt, 
  }{\checkmark}%
}



\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\logo}{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
    colframe=red,
    colback=red!35,
    top=0pt,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    tcbox raise base}

\newcounter{cenum}
\newcommand\cenumsep{}  
\newenvironment{cenumerate}{%
  \setcounter{cenum}{0}%
  \setlength\parskip\bigskipamount
  \begin{center}%
}{%
  \end{center}%
}
\newcommand\citem{%
  \refstepcounter{cenum}%
  \par\cenumsep\logo{\arabic{cenum}}%
  \par\nobreak\vskip-\parskip\medskip\noindent\ignorespaces% \medskip is the distance between label and text, change as needed
}

\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{cenumerate}
\citem The item logo is centered above the sentence. $\checkmark$

\textbf{\textcolor{red}{This sentence is part of the above item, and so I do not want it enumerated.}}

\citem The item logo is centered above the sentence. $\checkmark$

\citem The item logo is centered above the sentence. $\checkmark$
\end{cenumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. This answers the posted question. The adverse effect that I tried to communicate in my comments does not seem to be occurring when I use the code related to the `newcommand` `\citem` --- I have spent the last half hour or so trying to figure out why it does, however, happen for "exactly" the same circumstances except for using a regular `enumerate` with `\item` instead of the above, and ignoring the customized logo. Perhaps that's a question for another day when I can illustrate it better. In any case, I thank you once again for your helpful answer and comments.